# Buttons to show or hide divs using single method

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following snippets:
My HTML Page which uses 4 buttons to show/hide four divs, each will have their own content.

```js
var otherDivs = ["addCustomer", "searchCustomer", "addItem", "searchItem"];

function show(target) {

  var index = otherDivs.indexOf(target);
  for (i = 0; i < otherDivs.length; i++) {
    if (i != index) {
      $(document.getElementById(otherDivs[i].toString())).hide();
    } else {
      $(document.getElementById(otherDivs[i].toString())).show();
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 10px;">
  <div class="row" name="tabs">
    <button class="redButton" onclick="show('addCustomer')">Add Customer</button>
    <button class="redButton" onclick="show('searchCustomer')">Search Customers</button>
    <button class="redButton" onclick="show('addItem')">Add Item</button>
    <button class="redButton" onclick="show('searchItem')">Search Item</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row trigger" name="searchCustomer" id="searchCustomer">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="row trigger" name="addCustomer" id="addCustomer">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="row trigger" name="addItem" id="addItem">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="row trigger" name="searchItem" id="searchItem">
    ...
  </div>

</div>
```

The problem is, only the fist button and div (addCustomer) works correctly. I have tried split methods but I would prefer to keep the single method. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how about toggle?

Comment: could you perhaps post a link to an example?

Comment: Your code working correctly just change the content, check my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery fully when you have it.

Although with your HTML and inline script this would work:

```
function show(target) {
  $('.trigger').hide();
  $("#"+ target).show();
}
```

As could this (but it would not work as a radio button more like a checkbox):

```
function show(target) {
  $("#"+ target).toggle();
}
```

I strongly suggest you use unobtrusive code and move the script out of the HTML

```js
$(function() {
  $(".redButton").on("click",function() { // any button
    $(".trigger").hide(); // hide the divs
    $("#"+$(this).data("id")).show(); // show the relevant div
  });
});
```

```css
.trigger { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 10px;">
  <div class="row" name="tabs">
    <button type="button" class="redButton" data-id="addCustomer">Add Customer</button>
    <button type="button" class="redButton" data-id="searchCustomer">Search Customers</button>
    <button type="button" class="redButton" data-id="addItem">Add Item</button>
    <button type="button" class="redButton" data-id="searchItem">Search Item</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row trigger" name="searchCustomer" id="searchCustomer">
    Search Customer
  </div>
  <div class="row trigger" name="addCustomer" id="addCustomer">
    Add Customer
  </div>
  <div class="row trigger" name="addItem" id="addItem">
    Add Item
  </div>
  <div class="row trigger" name="searchItem" id="searchItem">
    Search Item
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually your code working properly but the thing is that you cannot specfiy which `div` is opened now because all `divs` have the same content, so when you add numbers or a different content you can know which one is opened now

```js
var otherDivs = ["addCustomer", "searchCustomer", "addItem", "searchItem"];

function show(target) {

  var index = otherDivs.indexOf(target);
  for (i = 0; i < otherDivs.length; i++) {
    if (i != index) {
      $(document.getElementById(otherDivs[i].toString())).hide();
    } else {
      $(document.getElementById(otherDivs[i].toString())).show();
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 10px;">
  <div class="row" name="tabs">
    <button class="redButton" onclick="show('addCustomer')">Add Customer</button>
    <button class="redButton" onclick="show('searchCustomer')">Search Customers</button>
    <button class="redButton" onclick="show('addItem')">Add Item</button>
    <button class="redButton" onclick="show('searchItem')">Search Item</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row trigger" name="searchCustomer" id="searchCustomer">
    .11..
  </div>
  <div class="row trigger" name="addCustomer" id="addCustomer">
    .22..
  </div>
  <div class="row trigger" name="addItem" id="addItem">
    .33..
  </div>
  <div class="row trigger" name="searchItem" id="searchItem">
    .44..
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpy use the JQuery `toggle` function like so

```
function show(target) {
  $('#'+target).toggle();
}
```

You could replace your entire JS in the snippet to just these LOC. HTML remains the same.

```js
function show(target) {
  $('#'+target).toggle();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 10px;">
  <div class="row" name="tabs">
    <button class="redButton" onclick="show('addCustomer')">Add Customer</button>
    <button class="redButton" onclick="show('searchCustomer')">Search Customers</button>
    <button class="redButton" onclick="show('addItem')">Add Item</button>
    <button class="redButton" onclick="show('searchItem')">Search Item</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row trigger" name="searchCustomer" id="searchCustomer">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="row trigger" name="addCustomer" id="addCustomer">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="row trigger" name="addItem" id="addItem">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="row trigger" name="searchItem" id="searchItem">
    ...
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This would not close the other open divs

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer

```js
    function show(target) {

    $("#Display").html( $('#' + target).html());
      
      
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 10px;">
      <div class="row" name="tabs">
        <button class="redButton" onclick="show('addCustomer')">Add Customer</button>
        <button class="redButton" onclick="show('searchCustomer')">Search Customers</button>
        <button class="redButton" onclick="show('addItem')">Add Item</button>
        <button class="redButton" onclick="show('searchItem')">Search Item</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row trigger" name="searchCustomer" id="searchCustomer" hidden>
        Searching Customers
      </div>
      <div class="row trigger" name="addCustomer" id="addCustomer" hidden>
        Customers added
      </div>
      <div class="row trigger" name="addItem" id="addItem" hidden>
        Items added
      </div>
      <div class="row trigger" name="searchItem" id="searchItem" hidden>
         Searching Items
      </div>
<div id="Display">
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This would only open a close the corresponding div, not close the others when clicked